# How to build a DataDriven (CMS) Driven Navigation with Next Js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

The navigation links for my website come from a CMS API end point. They could change at any time so they always need to be up-to-date based on what the API returns.

I tried to use getServerSideProps() inside my _app.js file, but it turns out that Nextjs doesn't allow you to do this.

So my question is how do you build a navigation that will be rendered on every page that is driven via fetching data from an API?

Comment: Create a `Page` component and use it in your `_app.jsx` and get your navigation menus in there using `getServerSideProps` or equivalent

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed - according to the documentation you can't call getServerSideProps inside _app.js

Comment: I didn't mention that your `Page` component should be in `_app.jsx`